# Directory disappear after "mv"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lost

This is my hell:

1º HD 140Gb SATA have a linux sistem
2º HD 140Gb SATA have a extended partition mounted in fstab:

```
/dev/sdb1       /media/backup   ext3    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

The first HD have only 1,2Mb Free and need to move from HD to HD2 data.. ok y execute has root this:

```
mv /var/www/WORKS /media/backup
```

This comand execute INSTANT (/var/www/WORKS have aprox 80Gb of data), and /var/www/WORKS DISAPPEAR, but in /media/backup not have nothing...

The case is in /dev/sda1 continue only free 1,2Mb... but directory /var/www/WORKS dosent exists.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, `/var/www/WORKS` was a symlink and all the files in it are still exactly where they were originally. You just moved the link, so you can no longer use the path `/var/www/WORKS` to reach them.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your `/dev/sdb1` wasn't mounted so all you did was move the `/var/www/WORKS` directory to `/media/backup`. Check that `/media/backup/WORKS` exists and if it does move it back again.

```
mv /meda/backup/WORKS /var/www
```

Then try mounting /dev/sdb1

```
mount /dev/sdb1
```

If you get an error message `mount: /dev/sdb1 already mounted ...` then your problem probably lies elsewhere.